# Ruby On Rails Case sensitive string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have params[:location] that should accept Left PA and Right PA it should not matter if we pass PA Left, Pa LEFT, Pa left, pa left, etc. I have to convert it to Left PA and similar with Right PA.

```
if params[:source] == 'abc'
  'ABC'
elsif params[:source] == 'DEF'
  'DEF'
else
  params[:source]
end
```

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `downcase/upcase` method to compare. And instead of `if/else` you can use `case`

```
case params[:location].to_s.downcase
  when 'pa left'
    'Left PA'
  when 'pa right'
    'Right PA'
  else 
    params[:location]
end
```